# Save DB query into an array and group all entries of user_id into one array entry

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I currently have a database with a user entry TABLE - where I query out something like:

```
user_id: 1
user_point: 20

user_id: 1
user_point: 50

user_id: 2
user_point: 10
```

This data is saved into an array, which looks like this:

```
$highscoreData = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  $highscoreData []= (object) array(
     "user_id" => $row['user_id'],
     "username" => $row['username'],
     "user_firstname" => $row['user_firstname'],
     "user_lastname" => $row['user_lastname'],
     "user_point" => $row['user_point']
  );
}
$feedback = $highscoreData;
```

1. How do I save my array where I GROUP entries based on `user_id` , so that that `user_id = 1` will only appear once in the array with a related added up `user_point` - which in this case would equal to "70 points"?
2. And how do I afterwards sort the array, so that the `user_id` with highest number of `user_point` will line up first in the array?

For question 1 - I figured to do something like a for loop:

```
for( var i = 0; i < highscoreData.length; i++ ){
  //check if user_id = user_id - then perhaps save into a new array?
}
```

For question 2 - looked at [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) - but not totally sure how to use it in this context

Any help, examples would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it: I could not describe in detail for time limitation

```
<?php

$highscoreData []= (object) array(
     "user_id" => 1,
     "username" => 'name1',
     "user_firstname" => "First Name 1",
     "user_lastname" => "Last Name 1",
     "user_point" => 20
  );

 $highscoreData []= (object) array(
     "user_id" => 1,
     "username" => 'name1',
     "user_firstname" => "First Name 1",
     "user_lastname" => "Last Name 1",
     "user_point" => 50
  );

$highscoreData []= (object) array(
     "user_id" => 2,
     "username" => 'name2',
     "user_firstname" => "First Name 2",
     "user_lastname" => "Last Name 2",
     "user_point" => 80
  );

$user_point_sum = array();
$users = array();
foreach($highscoreData as $array) {
  //check if user_id = user_id - then perhaps save into a new array?
  $user_id = $array->user_id;
  $username = $array->username;
  $user_firstname = $array->user_firstname;
  $user_lastname = $array->user_lastname;
  $user_point = $array->user_point;

  if(!isset($user_point_sum[$user_id])) {

     $user_point_sum[$user_id] = 0;

     $user_info = new stdClass();
     $user_info->user_id = $user_id;
     $user_info->username = $username;
     $user_info->user_firstname = $user_firstname;
     $user_info->user_lastname = $user_lastname;
     $users[$user_id] = $user_info;
  }
  $user_point_sum[$user_id] += $user_point;
}

arsort($user_point_sum);

$array_object = array();
foreach($user_point_sum as $user_id=>$user_point) {

    $object = new stdClass();

    $object->user_id = $user_id;
    $object->username = $users[$user_id]->username;
    $object->user_firstname = $users[$user_id]->user_firstname;
    $object->user_lastname = $users[$user_id]->user_lastname;
    $object->user_point = $user_point;

    $array_object[] = $object;
}

var_dump($array_object);

?>

Output:

array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[6]
      public 'user_id' => int 2
      public 'username' => string 'name2' (length=5)
      public 'user_firstname' => string 'First Name 2' (length=12)
      public 'user_lastname' => string 'Last Name 2' (length=11)
      public 'user_point' => int 80
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'user_id' => int 1
      public 'username' => string 'name1' (length=5)
      public 'user_firstname' => string 'First Name 1' (length=12)
      public 'user_lastname' => string 'Last Name 1' (length=11)
      public 'user_point' => int 70
```

Comment: Hi Salim - thanks so much for taking the time with a response - appreciate it! I see it working in my code - im just wondering how i'd incoorparate my other fields like: "user_firstname" => $row['user_firstname'] etc into your solution? And is it possible to save the new array as an array object, just like the initial and first array created from my query?

Comment: Edited answer as your requirements, please let me know your feed back

Comment: Hi Salim - will just have a look at it before leaving tonight and let you know, again thanks so much for taking the time to extend this!

Comment: Salim - it works nothing less than perfect! No questions or anything it makes sence and seeing we now make an object out of it, it fits in perfectly with the logic i've managed to build. Can't thank you enough for taking the time to extend your answer - you're a true champ! Thanks a gain